# ReadyAPI docker error, The license is invalid: Failed to get floating license. Reason: Failed to create HTTPS service for floating license server

Tags: docker, soapui, ready-api

When trying to run ready-api-soapui-testrunner via docker I get the above error, I am using a floating licence and can ping the server locally.

Below is the docker run command.

```html
docker run --net=bridge --add-host=TESTDB:10.30.214.251 -v="$project_dir":/project -v="$project_dir":/reports -e LICENSE_SERVER="10.0.21.14:1099" -e COMMAND_LINE="-E TestEnv /readyapi-project" -it smartbear/ready-api-soapui-testrunner:latest
```

and also the output I am getting.

```html
Please select the tool for which you want to get the floating license:
1. SoapUI Pro
2. LoadUI Pro
3. Secure (if you have an old license)
4. ServiceV Pro
5. VirtServer
6. ReadyAPI Bundle
7. TestEngine
8. swaggerhub
9. swaggerhub2
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/usr/local/SmartBear/ready-api-license-manager-1.3.2.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
ERROR: The license is invalid: Failed to get floating license. Reason: Failed to create HTTPS service for floating license server.
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you are using a floating license (may be provided by your employer), try checking your proxy settings, if possible use no proxy while doing license verification.

Answer (score 1):

So this issue turned out to be the container image not being compatible with my companies licencing server version. Specifing the smartbear/ready-api-soapui-testrunner:{version} fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Any idea where to look for compatibility between licensing server and docker image versions?

Comment: Some issue also for me.